# Create Trigger in Oracle, in order to check two Dates

Tags: oracle, triggers

I would like to create a Trigger in Oracle, in order to check the Current Date with the Date that is stored in a specific column and if they are equal, I would like to change a boolean value on the same table. I am new to Oracle and especially on creating triggers. Any help is much appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE DISCIPLINARYAUDIT 
(
  DISCIPLINARYAUDITID NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL 
, DISCIPLINARYAUDITTYPE VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL 
, REVOCATIONORCOMPLETION NUMBER(1, 0) 
, STARTDATE DATE 
, ENDDATE DATE 
)
```

When **endDate** equals with current Date, **RevocationORCompletion** must chenage from 0 to 1.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: DDL of the table, sample data and expected output, Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example.

Date format and today's date:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.
```

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, specific_column date, boolean_column varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (1, trunc(sysdate), 'FALSE');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values (2, trunc(sysdate) - 2, 'FALSE');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test order by id;

        ID SPECIFIC_C BOOLEAN_CO
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 04.06.2020 FALSE
         2 02.06.2020 FALSE
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_biu_test
  2    before insert or update on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if :new.specific_column = trunc(sysdate) then
  6       :new.boolean_column := 'TRUE';
  7    end if;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> update test set id = 3 where id = 1;

1 row updated.

SQL> update test set id = 5 where id = 2;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID SPECIFIC_C BOOLEAN_CO
---------- ---------- ----------
         3 04.06.2020 TRUE
         5 02.06.2020 FALSE

SQL>
```

Comment: ````
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dateCheck
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON disciplinaryaudit
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :new.enddate = trunc(sysdate) then
       :new.revocationorcompletion := "TRUE";
    END IF;
END;
````
I did something like that, but no change... Guess I am doing something wrong.

Comment: What is obvious is that you used double quotes `"TRUE"`; should be single, as in my example. If that's not what you meant to comment, what was it, then?

Comment: The REVOCATIONORCOMPLETION column is declared as NUMBER(1, 0). So I'm not sure that it will work with TRUE or FALSE. Never the less, i tried, instead of writing 'TRUE', to write 1, or '1', but nothing happens. If it would work, the changes should be visible with a refresh on the table, right?

Comment: Yes; if column is NUMBER, then you'd put 1 for TRUE in there, that's OK. If nothing happens, check what is stored into ENDDATE. Does that column contain only date, or date **and time**? If it is both, then try `if trunc(:new.enddate) = trunc(sysdate) then ...`

Comment: It stores only date. For example it stores 04/06/20

Comment: Are you sure? Run `select to_char(enddate, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from disciplinaryaudit`. What do you see?

Comment: 04.06.2020 00:00:00 This is what I get with the statement you just posted.

Comment: Right, it is date only. Just to make sure: you created a trigger and then updated some rows (by running `UPDATE disciplinaryaudit SET ...`. Trigger fired and *did something* (or did not). Then you checked changes by `select * from disciplinaryaudit ...` and you didn't see `1` in rows whose enddate is equal to sysdate. Is that correct?

Comment: Nevermind... It works. I thought that it would UPDATE the already stored endDate but it didn't. I run a scenario right now with storing a new endDate and set it on todays date and the REVOCATIONORCOMPETION has changed to 1

Comment: Thank you so much for your time!! Really appreciate it.

Comment: Aha, OK. You got it wrong; trigger - when created - doesn't do anything with existing data. It fires when row is inserted or updated, but - then again - it doesn't modify data that previously existed in that table. I'm glad you made it work, you're welcome.